# Wicket NumberTextField in Kotlin throws ClassCastException when submitted

Tags: wicket, kotlin

I'm having some issues with a Wicket (8.0.0-M4) NumberTextField in Kotlin (1.1.0).

My stripped-down form looks like this:

```
class Test : AbstractWebPage() {

    val housenumberModel: Model<Int> = Model<Int>()
    val housenumber = NumberTextField<Int>("housenumberModel", housenumberModel)

    val form: Form<Unit> = object : Form<Unit>("adressForm") {}

    override fun onInitialize() {
        super.onInitialize()

        form.add(housenumber.setRequired(false))
        form.add(object : SubmitLink("submit") {
            override fun onSubmit() {
                super.onSubmit()
                println(housenumberModel.`object`)  // this is line 28
            }

        })
        add(form)
    }

}
```

After submitting the form I get the following stacktrace:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to
>   java.lang.Number
>        at com.mycompany.test.pages.Test$onInitialize$1.onSubmit(Test.kt:28)
>        at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.delegateSubmit(Form.java:1312)
>        at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.process(Form.java:979)
>        at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.onFormSubmitted(Form.java:802)
>        at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.onRequest(Form.java:715)
>        at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.ListenerRequestHandler.internalInvoke(ListenerRequestHandler.java:301)
>        at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.ListenerRequestHandler.invoke(ListenerRequestHandler.java:250)
>        at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.ListenerRequestHandler.invokeListener(ListenerRequestHandler.java:210)
>        at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.ListenerRequestHandler.respond(ListenerRequestHandler.java:203)
>        at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle$HandlerExecutor.respond(RequestCycle.java:912)
>        at org.apache.wicket.request.RequestHandlerExecutor.execute(RequestHandlerExecutor.java:65)
>        at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.execute(RequestCycle.java:283)
>        at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequest(RequestCycle.java:253)
>        at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequestAndDetach(RequestCycle.java:221)
>        at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequestCycle(WicketFilter.java:262)
>        at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequest(WicketFilter.java:204)
>        at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doFilter(WicketFilter.java:286)
>   [...]

If I use

```
val housenumberModel: Model<Int> = Model.of(0)
```

instead of

```
val housenumberModel: Model<Int> = Model<Int>()
```

everything works fine. But since my NumberTextField is optional I don't want to have it pre-initialized with 0.

Me and my colleagues were trying to change the type signature of the Model in every way we could imagine but came to no solution. A co-worker suggested to write a custom Wicket converter since Kotlins Int is represendeted as a primitive type (From the docs: "On the JVM, non-nullable values of this type are represented as values of the primitive type int.") Even though I don't know yet if this would work it seems like an overkill for me.

Another hack I could think of: writing some JavaScript to delete the zero from the input field. Also not really something I would want to do.

Question: Is there a simple solution to my problem?

(And as a bonus-question: has already anyone written a larger Wicket application in Kotlin and could tell me if this combination is ready for prime time to develop a critical project with this stack or is my problem just the tip of the iceberg?)

[edit]

Solution as pointed out by svenmeier:

Using

```
val housenumber = NumberTextField<Int>("housenumberModel", housenumberModel, Int::class.java)
```

works.

Or as an alternative:

```
val housenumbervalue: Int?  = null
val housenumberModel: IModel<Int> = PropertyModel<Int>(this, "housenumbervalue")
val housenumber = NumberTextField<Int>("housenumberModel", housenumberModel)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because of type erasure your NumberTextField cannot detect the generic type parameter of your model. Since your model object is null, it cannot be used to derive the type either.

In this case Wicket assumes a String model object type :/.

Either provide the type to the NumberTextField explicitly, or use a model that keeps its generic information, e.g. a PropertyModel.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to tell wicket about the type you want, it is by adding the type in the constructor. More [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/8.x/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/form/NumberTextField.html#NumberTextField-java.lang.String-org.apache.wicket.model.IModel-java.lang.Class-).

In Java it looks like this:

```
new NumberTextField<Integer>("housenumberModel", housenumberModel, Integer.class);
```